# WSO2IS adding user by API

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I try to use wso2is API (RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl) to create a new user. I can delete a user ,logon but I can't add a user .There is an Exception adding new user : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method addUser
I set valid password met password policy.
 Heare is my code :

```
 AuthenticationAdminStub authstub = new AuthenticationAdminStub();
            String cookie = null;
            String auid = ConfigUtil.getProperty(ConfigUtil.MOM_ADMINID_INFO);
            String apassword = ConfigUtil.getProperty(ConfigUtil.MOM_ADMINPASS_INFO);
            Login login = new Login();
            login.setUsername(auid);
            login.setPassword(apassword);
            login.setRemoteAddress(APP_ID);
            LoginResponse res = authstub.login(login);
            //realm.
            if (res.get_return())
                cookie = (String) authstub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().getProperty(
                        HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING);

            RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub realm = new RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub();
            ServiceClient serviceClient = realm._getServiceClient();
            Options option = serviceClient.getOptions();
            option.setManageSession(true);
            option.setProperty(HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING, cookie);
            IsExistingUser user = new IsExistingUser();
            user.setUserName(username);
            IsExistingUserResponse resEx = realm.isExistingUser(user);
            if (resEx.get_return()) {
                DeleteUser duser = new DeleteUser();
                duser.setUserName(username);
                realm.deleteUser(duser);
            }
            RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.AddUser aUser = new RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.AddUser();
            aUser.setUserName(username);
            RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.ClaimValue[] claim = new RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.ClaimValue[1];
            claim[0] = new RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.ClaimValue();
            claim[0].setClaimURI("http://wso2.org/claims/businessphone");
            claim[0].setValue("0112842302");
            aUser.setClaims(claim);
            aUser.setCredential(password);
            aUser.setRoleList(new String[]{APP_ID, null});
            realm.addUser(aUser);
```

I generated stubs java code by axis2 ant generation code and add axis codes to my project.
can any one help me. thanks.

Comment: You can able user core debug logs of WSO2IS  and add the logs in to the question. Then it is easy to know the actual issue http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/02/26/how-to-wso2is-troubleshooting-wso2-identity-server-1/

Comment: thanks. I enabled debug mod. here is Exception details on wso2is log :DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     SearchRequest
        baseDn : 'uid=09123456789,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org'
        filter : '(&(2.5.4.0=person)(0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=09123456789))'
        scope : whole subtree
        typesOnly : false
        Size Limit : no limit
        Time Limit : no limit
        Deref Aliases : deref Always
        attributes :

Comment: ERR_259 Attempt to search under non-existant entry:  uid=09123456789,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org]; remaining name 'uid=09123456789,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org'
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3112)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3033)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2840)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1849)

Comment: What is user search based defined in user-mgt.xml file ? Is it "ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org" ? or any other?